# What is the difference between "social butterfly" and "socialite"?

Tags: meaning

I think both are one and the same but that word socialite may best describe a person formally and it may also describe person's lifestyle while social butterfly describes person who socializes at an outing such as parties. Please help me understand the difference.

If they're one and same but difference is in formality, please let me know!

Comment: Please look up the words in a good dictionary and let us know what you found, to help us help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A socialite is someone with a reputation for participating in many social activities.

A social butterfly is someone with a reputation for being very social when they do participate in social activities.

A person can be on either one or both at the same time!

Comment: Socialite is exactly what I am looking for, just that first thing that came to mind was social butterfly which made me confused.

Comment: We need to cite our sources.